# Xpath to read tags and attributes as String

Tags: xpath, dom4j

I have the following xml content that I would like to read everything inside ref as one string with xpath in dom4j api, basically 
I want

```
<list>
  <ref id="R1">
    <citation type="book">
      <name>John</name>
      <title>News</title>
    </citation>
  </ref>
  <ref id="R2">
    <citation type="journal">
      <name>Jane</name>
      <title>Finance</title>
    </citation>
  </ref>
</list>
```

to output as raw strings including the tags, and attributes

```
<citation type="book"> <name>John</name><title>News</title></citation> 
<citation type="journal"> <name>Jane</name><title>Finance</title></citation>
```

My code is

```
org.dom4j.Document doc = DomReader.parse("test.xml");
List<Node> nodes = doc.selectNodes("/list/ref" );
for (Node node : nodes)
{
    System.out.println( node.getStringValue());
}
```

The above code just gives me the values John, News, Jane, Finance.

But I want the whole thing included.

Comment: I used **node.asXML()**; and it gives the result as expected more or less. It gives <ref id="R1"><citation type="book"> <name>John</name><title>News</title></citation>   </ref>

Answer (score 0):

The `.getStringValue()` method is defined to return the XPath "string value" of the node, which for an element means the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.  For the XML representation of the node you need to use the [`.asXML()` method](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.4/apidocs/org/dom4j/Node.html#asXML%28%29) instead.